# How to implement authentication in a Panel app

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh, pyviz

Is there a way to authenticate a [Panel](https://panel.pyviz.org/) app? So that it cannot be directly accessed by it's URL.

The Panel serves a Jupyter Notebook and is being run through command line.

What I'm trying to achieve is to pass a token in the header of each request to a Panel. Or any other way through which it can be made secured.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you try to do but by default Panel is not accessible to external requests if you do not specify *--allow-websocket-origin*. So is only accessible locally.

For exemple, you can have a server for basic authentication, then redirect to panel app.

Having said this, if you want to pass some argument to a panel you can access [session state](https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Deploy_and_Export.html)